# How does python max(list) function work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code that doesn't work the way it should.

```
n = int(input())
arr = map(int, input().split())

num=max(arr)
x=list(set(arr))
print (x)
```

This returns and empty list "[]".
However, if I remove the num=max[arr] line from the code, it works as expected.

```
n = int(input())
arr = map(int, input().split())

x=list(set(arr))
print (x)
```

And the output is a list of all elements without duplicates.
I wanted to use the max() value somewhere else in the program, but it seems to break the list formation. Why does this happen? Is there a basic property of the max function that I'm missing?

Edit: Why are people downvoting this without any answers? I'm fairly new to python and any help would be appreciated. If I made a silly mistake please point that out.

Comment: In Python 3.x, `map()` returns a lazy iterator (rather than an actual list as in earlier versions).  When you call `max()` on this iterator, all of its elements are consumed, making it appear empty for any further operations.  Putting `ar = list(ar)` as the third line in your code would make an actual list out of it, which can be iterated as many times as you want.

Comment: I was wondering wth was happening since I use mostly python 2.7. You learn something new every day

Comment: @jasonharper That makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n = int(input())  # unused - why put it in your example?
arr = map(int, input().split())  # returns an iterator

num=max(arr)      # consumes the iterator
x=list(set(arr))  # nothing in the iterator anymore
print (x)         # prints nothing
```

Fix:

```
n = int(input())  # unused - why put it in your example?
arr = set(map(int, input().split()))  # returns an set named arr

num=max(arr)      # get num as max from set 
print (arr)       # prints the set named arr
```

In python 2 map behaved differently - for 3 its an iterator. Once consumed, iterators are "empty". You can see for yourself if you `print(type(arr))` for the result of *your* map operation.

Read: [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

Comment: Really like all the comment and explanations gives in this answer , like a good teacher

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need to use map in this case. Another thing is that you will throw errors on your input if the user does not provide a single int since you are trying to convert it. You can take your input, like a string of '1 4 6 23 5', convert it to a list of ints, and then find the max.

```
n = '1 4 6 23 5'
arr = [int(x) for x in n.split()]
max(arr)
```

Comment: how does your solution prevent throwing errors when someone provides a string with non-integers in it?