# Max value from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list that consists of temperatures

```
['24', '7', '5', '34', '41', '41', '4', '24', '45', '41']
```

when I attempt to get the max value by using

```
maxTList = ['24', '7', '5', '34', '41', '41', '4', '24', '45', '41']
print(max(maxTList))
```

I got a return value of `7`. What gives? Where am I going wrong? I am expecting to return a value of `45`.

Comment: It is because your values are of type 'str', so it is doing some weird max() which also factors in the length of each string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does python max(list) function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930003/how-does-python-maxlist-function-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have are strings, not numbers. You can cast them to ints when computing the max or change your entire list to ints:

```
max(maxTList, key=int)
```

or

```
num_list = [int(x) for x in maxTList]
max(num_list)
```

Comment: Or just `max([int(x) for x in maxTList])`.